# Time Complexity Analysis of naive Caesar Cypher

Tags: find, time-complexity, caesar-cipher

I began doing practice problems for job interviewing and when I was solving Caesar Cypher the naive solution I came up with at first glance was something like this.

```
def caesarCipherEncryptor(string, key): 
    abc = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    key = key % 26

    letter = 0
    result = ''

    for char in string:
        index = abc.find(char)
        result += abc[index + key]

    return result
```

My understanding of time complexity is still very basic.

My question is... The main chunk of my naive solution focuses on the find function which is o(n) on the string: abc I have passed. Since it does o(n) operations on each character for the string it needs to cipher does that mean it's o(n^2). I was also thinking the whole operation is just o(n) due to the one-pass nature of the solution coupled thinking the find(char) operation is a constant at worst case finding the index to be 'z' (25th index). Should my analysis on time complexity be purely in perspective of the input string?

Answer (score 0):

let the length of the given string be equal n. (always explain what the n means!)

Your algorithm, goes over each character of 'string' and for each one:

search it in 26 size array

perform one simple mathematical operation.

thus, the time complexity of your algorithm is n(26+1)

Asymptotically, it can be said your algorithm is O(n) and even Theta(n)

With a little bit of work, you can show that any correct algorithm that solves the problem perform at least n operation, thus,  asymptotically, your algorithm is as efficient as it gets. (in other words, this problem is Omega(n) )